# tengo problemas al cambiar la posicion de un elemento de array, sin que se repita ningun elemento

Tags: javascript

```
var palos = ['P','T','C','D'];
var palos2= palos;
var almacenInicial1 = palos[elecion];
var almacenInicial2 = palos[elecion2];

for(var i= 0;i<10;i++){

var elecion = Math.floor(Math.random()*palos.length);
var elecion2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*palos.length);

palos2[elecion2]= palos2[elecion];
palos2[elecion]=palos2[elecion2];
}
```

Estoy creando un programa lo cual me permite barajar los elementos del array,
el objetivo es que el programa cambie las posiciones  'sin que se repita ningun elemento'. Pero se me repiten los elementos.
E investigado y lo que pude entender es que debo de almacenar dos posiciones aleatorias y almacenarlas cada una por individual, despues cambiar la posicion 1 por la dos y viceversa y asi no deberia de repetirse ningun elemento. 
Pero solo se repiten los elementos, y no logro conseguir cambiar los elementos sin que se me repitan , Gelp me, Please!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No te compliques tanto, puedes usar [`sort`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_sort.asp):

```
var palos = ['P','T','C','D'];
var palos2 = palos.slice().sort(function(a, b){return 0.5 - Math.random()});
                // ^^^^ .slice() para crear una copia del array original y no hacerle sort
```

Usando `slice` creamos una copia del array `palos` y después hacemos el sorting, esto por si no quieres modificar el array `palos`, igual si esto no importa puedes aplicar el método `sort` directamente a `palos`.

```
var palos = ['P','T','C','D'].sort(function(a, b) {return 0.5 - Math.random()});
```